# filter and display selected results from a R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
column_name<-c("a","b","c","d","e")
first_column<-c(1,2,5,4,5)
second_column<-c(1,6,3,4,5)
df<-data.frame(column_name,first_column,second_column)

df$difference<-first_column-second_column
df$check_difference<-ifelse(df$difference!=0,"error",0)

> df
  column_name first_column second_column difference check_difference
1           a            1             1          0                0
2           b            2             6         -4            error
3           c            5             3          2            error
4           d            4             4          0                0
5           e            5             5          0                0
```

May I ask, if I wanna get the following result, what should I do?

```
Number of error in the dataset is "2"
Error found in column "b"
Error found in column "c"
```

Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
sprintf('Number of error in the dataset is "%s"', 
        sum(df$check_difference == 'error')) |> 
  cat()
sprintf('Error found in column "%s"', 
        df[ df$check_difference == 'error', 'column_name']) |> 
  cat(sep = '\n')
```